# How can I hide the default Administrator account folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

After enabling, loging in once and disabling the default Administrator account, I can see the user folder named 'Administrators' inside my Users folder. How can I hide the folder like it was hidden before?

Comment: It wasn’t hidden.  It didn’t exist.  It was created when you log into the account.  Disable the account, take ownership of the directory, then delete it.

Comment: Or better - use a tool like [delprof](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/) to properly delete user profile data (will delete registry entry related to the account, and the actual folder). If you simply deleted the folder and for whatever reason you decided to re-use the same username - you may ends up with Temporary Profile.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by user @Darius, I successfully disabled the Administrator account via command prompt and then used [delprof](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/) to delete the remaining folder inside the Users directory.

**Note** that deleting this folder means that the Administrator account will run the entire set up process every time. To avoid this, I've added a password to the Administrator account, disabled it, but left the user folder in place. Whenever I enable it and log back in, all my previous settings are restored.